# OOP C#: how to write a method for spitting out arrays that works in both WinForm and Console?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm trying to write a method that will be usable in both winform and the console.

Here's my code:

```
  public class BeerKoozie
    {
        public bool IsSinging = false;
        //Your classes aren't working because you didn't have a constructor method.
        public BeerKoozie()
        {
            for (int beerCount = 0; beerCount < 100; beerCount++)
            {
                beerCollection[beerCount] = new Beer();

                if (beerCount == 99)
                {
                    IsSinging = true;
                }
            }
        }




        //needs a collection representing one hundred beers.
        Beer[] beerCollection = new Beer[100];

        // needs a notion of a current beer
        public int CurrentBeer = 99;

        // needs a notion of going to the next beer.
        public string DrinkAbeerAndSingTheSong()
        {
            //BeerKoozie.bee
            //foreach (Beer value in beerCollection)
            //foreach (Beer value in beerCollection)
            do(Beer i in beerCollection)
            {
                beerCollection[CurrentBeer].IsFull = false;

                CurrentBeer--;



            } while (CurrentBeer > 0);

            return CurrentBeer.ToString() + "... beers on the wall";

        }
```

Whenever I try to print `beerCollection[CurrentBeer]` out with `.ToString` on the end the name of the method just prints out.  So, which pattern should be used for a platform agnostic method that iterates through the entire array, while keeping the business end and view separate?  I can easily write a method that works for only console or winform with their specific handly of strings.  **(My code isn't compilable since I broke it when messing around with the method, and cannot get it back to how it was before.  I also have fully functional code right now, so cannot reproduce the issue.)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where to start with this??!!!?? I don't think there is any possible remotely conceivable way this could have compiled.... I'm going to step through and build my answer up in increments.

Ok, with your loop, do this instead:

```
foreach(Beer i in beerCollection)
{
    i.IsFull = false;
}
```

Note the `while` is gone (it has nothing to do with a foreach iteration of a collection), and your publicly visible index/counter is gone.

Next, your loop in your constructor:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    beerCollection[i] = new Beer();
}

IsSinging = true;
```

Change `beerCount` to `i` - it's a semantic argument, `i` is a standard way of referring to a loop indexer and it's much shorter to type, you don't need a long descriptive name for it.
Note the `IsSinging` has been moved to outside of the loop - you simply need to set it at the end of the loop, you don't need a conditional statement to see if it's time to set it.

Lastly, to answer your question:

> how to write a method for spitting out arrays that works in both WinForm and Console?

This does work in both - arrays are a language construct and are totally independant of which type of project/executable you have set up. `BeerKoozie` is a class that can be used in either of those - simply add a new Class Library project to your solution, add the `BeerKoozie` class to that new project, then you can call it from any other project/assembly that references the new class project.

> Is there any way to return multiple times?

No, there is not. You have got yourself totally mixed up - the line `CurrentBeer.ToString() + "... beers on the wall";` needs to be inside the loop, otherwise what you are doing is calling the function, iterating through the entire collection and returning just once. I suggest you go with something similar to the following (I'm using a do/while loop as you requested):

```
public string DrinkAbeerAndSingTheSong()  
{  
    CurrentBeer = beerCollection.Length - 1;  //take 1 off, remember the array index is zero based   
    //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    do
    {
        beerCollection[CurrentBeer].IsFull = false;
        //sb.AddLine(CurrentBeer + "... beers on the wall");
        //Console.Writeline(CurrentBeer + "... beers on the wall");
        CurrentBeer--;
    } while (CurrentBeer > 0);

    return CurrentBeer + "... beers on the wall";
    //sb.AddLine(CurrentBeer + "... beers on the wall");  //don't forget the last line of the song
    //return sb.ToString();
}
```

With this you have a couple of options depending on what you are trying to achieve. You don't want to call the method 100 times to adjust the count and the state of the beers in the array, so you should do all the work inside the loop. I presume you want to either print out each line of the song as the action happens or you want to return the entire song, so I've included both those - simply uncomment the appropriate code and have a play.

Comment: Sorry, I had meant to post a do loop.

Comment: Is there any way to return multiple times?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was mixing myself up by trying to transfer the value of the beer array to a string array and then printing that out.  For whatever reason I had thought with OOP 'Console.WriteLine' was supposed to be left out of the class library.

Comment: Now, if I wanted to write it so the class library will work both in WinForm and Console.  Do I have to pass the beer array to a string array and then print it out, through each applications means of displaying a string?

Comment: @ZeroPhase Pass the `beerCollection` in to the function and then assemble the lines of the song using the StringBuilder, then either return the StringBuilder or do a `ToString()` to return it as a string.

Comment: That `sb.AppendLine()` makes the entire project extremely easy to perform.  I have a feeling the professor wanted us printing out each value of a string array.   In a few days I'll post alternative code.

Comment: @ZeroPhase Then add each line to a List<string>, and at the end of the function to a `ToArray()` on the list. The key thing is to keep the function reuseable - a known input should have a predictable output (also known as deterministic).